# "Our team" or "My team"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, email

I have to send a mail to a group which has my team members along with other co-workers. I want to write "Our team is drafting a report" since my team members are also present in the group. I think the correct format is "My team is drafting a report". But using "My" instead of "Our" feels possessive since I'm the junior most member of the team. What should I do? Go with "Our team" or "My team"?

Comment: 'Our team' is a lot more collegial-sounding, especially if (as you state) you are the team's most junior member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific case, I would use 'our'. As you stated, it does sound more collegial and inclusive. (And you're copying your teammates on the message.)

*Our* is appropriate for situations when you are communicating with someone else on the same team/in the same organization, when you want to be inclusive, and when you want to exhibit participatory leadership or don't have an official leadership role.

*My* is appropriate for situations when you do have an official leadership role, when you're communicating with someone outside your team/organization, when you'll be delegating the work or otherwise won't actually be doing the work yourself, or when you need to put on a show of strength. In spoken conversation, tone of voice can soften the "possessiveness" of *my*, but of course, written communication doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

Use **our** so it doesn't come across as **tail wagging the dog** :)